# A graph on the cities of a country

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

> In some country several pairs of cities are connected by direct
>   two-way flights. It is possible to go from any city to any other by a
>   sequence of flights. The distance between two cities is defined to be
>   the least possible numbers of flights required to go from one of them
>   to the other. It is known that for any city there are at most $100$
>   cities at distance exactly three from it. Prove that  there is no city
>   such that more than $2550$ other cities have distance exactly four
>   from it.

This problem is from the IMO Shortlist 2013. My first thought was constructing a graph with the cities as vertices. Now we have the graph is connected. But the rest seems a bit blurry to me. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be an _undirected_ graph, given the fact that the flights are two-way.

Comment: Oh, I need to stop posting wrong things. Sorry I will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a graph $G$ with a vertex corresponding to each city, and an edge between each pair of cities for which a flight between the cities exists. Consider any vertex $v \in V(G)$. Let $d_4(v)$ be the number of vertices of distance $4$ from $v$ in $G$. Let $\{v_1, v_2, \dots , v_p\}$ be the set of vertices of distance $1$ from $v$ in $G$. Now for each $i\in\{1,2,\dots,p\}$, let $V_i$ be the set of vertices $w$ not in any $V_j$ for $j<i$ at distance $4$ from $v$ for which a path of length $3$ not including $v$ exists between $v_i$ and $w$. Let $|V_i| = n_i$.

If all values of $n_i$ are zero, then $d_4(v) = 0$. So assume, without loss of generality, that $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_q$ are non-zero (if not, re-index so that this is the case). Now note that all vertices in $V_i$ are distance $3$ from $v_i$, and for each $j\in\{1,2,\dots,q\}$ different from $i$, there must be at least one additional vertex of distance $3$ from $v_i$. Now since no vertex can have more than $100$ vertices at distance $3$, we have for each $i \in \{1,2,\dots,q\}$:

$$n_i + q - 1 \leq 100$$

And we have that:

$$d_4(v) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{q} n_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^{q} (101 - q) = (101-q)q$$

But $f(q) = (101-q)q$ is maximum when $f'(q) = 101 - 2q = 0$, or when $q = \frac{101}{2}$, so we have:

$$d_4(v) \leq \left(101 - \frac{101}{2}\right)\frac{101}{2} = 2550.25$$

Thus the number of vertices at distance $4$ from any vertex is at most $2550$.

Comment: Hi, is it necessary that the nonzero $n-$ values are consecutive indices? I mean the $n_k$ which are nonzero could be $n_2,n_3,\ldots,n_{q+1}$ as well, couldn't it? Sorry if I am missing an obvious thing. Thanks.

Comment: @shadow10 No, it's not necessary, I assumed it for convenience. If it wasn't the case, you could simply re-index. Another possibility is to assume $n_{i_1}, n_{i_2}, \dots, n_{i_q}$ are the non-zero values, but I tend to try to avoid sub-indices where possible.

Comment: "and for each $j\in\{1,2,\dots,q\}$ different from $i$, there must be at least one additional vertex of distance $3$ from $v_i$."
Could you explain this line? Again I am sorry for not understanding it. Hope it is not something too trivial. Thanks @PerryIverson